# tkinter how to change a button's look/image in a specific state (disabled)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-button

I made my own button (so I'm using an image), it's just like decoration, it has to stay where it is but also be unclickable, when I set it to `"disabled'` state it gets a very ugly filter on it:

[image]

How can I make it unclickable without that ugly filter please?

Comment: Don't use windows.

Comment: Then why don't you just use a `Label` instead of `Button`?

Comment: There is a way to remove the entire title bar temporarily by invoking `overrideredirect` and implementing necessary controls

Comment: Try using images with transparent background, then there will be no *ugly filter* on them.

Answer (score 0):

This is an improved version of the previous code.

It will temporarily remove title bar and will restore it if necessary.

Key `F1` now controls title bar visibility by acting as a toggle switch.

Now the window can be picked up and moved with `Button-1` and `Motion` at any time.

Escape key or Alt F4 will close window.

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def showhide( ev ):
    ev.widget.lift()
    if root.overrideredirect(None):
        ev.widget.overrideredirect( 0 )
    else:
        ev.widget.overrideredirect( 1 )

def drag( ev = None ):
    global xpos, ypos, dragx, dragy, wide, high
    if root.overrideredirect(None):
        if dragx == 0 and dragy == 0:
            dragx, dragy = ev.x, ev.y
        xpos = xpos + ev.x - dragx
        ypos = ypos + ev.y - dragy
        if xpos < 0:  Xpos = 0
        if ypos < 0:  Ypos = 0
        xmax = root.winfo_screenwidth() - wide
        ymax = root .winfo_screenheight() - high
        if xpos > xmax:  xpos = xmax
        if ypos > ymax:  ypos = ymax
        root.geometry( f'+{xpos}+{ypos}')

def clear( ev ):
    global dragx, dragy
    dragx, dragy = 0, 0

def closer( ev = None ):
    root.destroy()

label = tk.Label(
    root,
    text = """Press F1 to hide or show window Title bar
Press Escape key or Alt-F4 to close program
You may now Pickup and drag window around

This movement modification thanks to @titoo

""",
    justify = "left", anchor = "center",
          width = 40, height = 20)
label.pack()

root.resizable( False, False )
root.update()

root.protocol( "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", closer )
root.bind( "<Escape>", closer )

dragx, dragy = 0, 0
xpos, ypos = root.winfo_x(), root.winfo_y()
wide, high = root.winfo_width(), root.winfo_height()

root.bind( "<F1>", showhide )
root.bind( '<B1-Motion>', drag )
root.bind( '<ButtonRelease-1>', clear )

drag( )

root.mainloop()
```